# I cannot edit snippet when improving edits

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, stack-snippets

As said in the title, when I find a pending edit and I try to improve it I cannot edit the snippet inside:

> [image]

I don't know if it was always the case but I am pretty sure I was able to do this before. It's probably a bug.

Here is some examples of pending edits:

<strike>https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21832295</strike>

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21849959

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21849904

---

Using Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Build officiel) (64 bits) on Windows 8.1 and no console errors.

Comment: You don't see the "edit the above snippet" link? https://i.stack.imgur.com/24gV5.png

Comment: @Stijn no I don't, you see it when you improve the edit?

Comment: Yes, I see it when clicking "improve edit". Using Firefox 64 on Windows 10.

Comment: No repro here, I can see the "edit the above snippet" link when either improving or reject/editing a review (Windows 10 - Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: I can't reproduce on [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21838374), exact same Chrome and OS as Nick

Comment: I also can't see it using your review link, but I can if I go to the question and edit it directly. Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @DaleBurrell Note that the review link in the OP now points to a *completed review*, while the screenshot where the link is missing is the interface after one has started editing.

Comment: Ar good point...

Comment: Since we can't repro, 'fess up.  This was just a sneaky way to get us to review, right? ;)

Comment: As a markedly imperfect work around, you could wait until the approval is completed and then go back and edit. If you're rejecting, you could go edit outside the queue and it will reject as a conflict.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's what I do, but it's a bit annoying to wait when you should be able to improve and easily adjust thing and the edit is done immediately. I will probably forget to come back later.