# Snippet controls appear twice after completing a review

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

TL;DR:

[image]

Reproduction steps:

- Find a post with a pending suggested edit to add a snippet; in my case, I handled the review from the "edit (1)" link rather than through /review.
- Switch to "rendered output" mode.
- I switched back to "markdown" mode before completing the review, but I don't know if that's necessary to reproduce.
- Complete the review.
- Switch back to "rendered output" mode.
- Observe that the snippet controls appear twice.

Comment: I usally get this and sometimes this too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378490/8620333 .. but it's a bit random for me

Comment: Is it just me or are the colours in your screenshot a bit off?

Comment: @CalvT must be the user's own color scheme or personal preference