# Can we re-open code (stack snippets) in the code editor?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, code

For example, given the following code snippet, how does one edit the question or answer and open the existing example inside the code editor again?

```js
console.log('example')
```

```css
h1 {
  color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example<h1>
```

It seems there is no such feature, so once a snippet is inserted, it becomes tedious to edit.

Comment: When you edit the question, there is a link below the snippet "edit the above snippet".

Comment: Note that if you don't see that link, we might want to revive [this bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378490/8967612).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ah, thanks. It was not obvious to look in the *preview* for that link. One may be looking in the post editor, or in the toolbar above the editor.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What I was intuitively trying to do what highlighting the entire text output of the code snippet, then hitting the Snippet button (or ctrl-m). I thought it would be smart enough to edit the selected snippet.